# Wi-Fi Interfering with Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, mouse

I have an issue with my Logitech MX Master when trying to connect to my Macbook Pro (Early 2015 retina base model) via Bluetooth. The mouse has a stable performance only when Wi-Fi is turned off. Once Wi-Fi is turned on, however, the mouse gets really laggy. The cursor skips/jumps randomly, and the mouse's connection becomes very spotty and sometimes flat out disconnects.

I've been reading other posts on Stack Exchange and Apple's forums, and it seems many other people have had similar issues. Is there any workaround? This issue is proving to be a huge inconvenience :(

Also, how come my mouse keeps having to reconnect as a new bluetooth device every time I pair it, instead of having it paired to the previously connected slot. Here's an image to show what I mean, since it's kind of confusing to put into words:

[image]

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: The first question might have an answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/91841/38539); Bluetooth and WiFi may be using the same band –– and interfere each other.

Comment: Since the mouse comes with two type of connection, which one are you using ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I am using the Logitech mouse via Bluetooth (so NOT with the unifying receiver).

Answer (score -1):

I moved over the MX to band 2, then turned my wifi  off and back on. Everything is fine now.